# FOSUserBundle 1.3.1 => 2.0

Tags: symfony, compatibility, fosuserbundle, symfony-2.2

I'm using 1.3.1 version of FOSUserBundle. I has upgraded symfony to 2.2 and I'm not sure about 1.3.1 compatibility so I want to upgrade the bundle as well, but I can't find any instructions of what I have to do. Is there any manual or kind of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In own experience there is no problem using FOSUserBundle v1.3.1 with symfony 2.2. You can still use it. But if you need new features (like the new events) than you must upgrade to `dev-master` or its `v2.0` alias. Unfortunately there is no tagged release available. Simply change the version string in composer to:

```
"friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "2.0.*@dev"
```

Comment: Yes, actually the question was how to migrate all my changes (form handlers overriding, controllers overriding, etc). I've got all answers here: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/issues/1127
So both controllers and form handlers can be overriden via form events now.

Comment: Ok, you didn't mention you override controller, .. And the event system is really nice.

Comment: Yes, I'm actually agreed with that.